# Why does the if statement not recognize what is in the list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I want the if statement to correctly compare what is in the list to what the input is in the enter_password variable.

```
user_password = []
password = input("Enter what you would like your password to be. \n ENTER: ")
user_password.append(password)
print(f"Password created! Your password is: {user_password}")
enter_password = input("Enter password: ")
if enter_password == user_password:
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print(f"{user_password} is wrong password")
```

Comment: Because a list doesn't equal a single string.

Comment: @deceze thanks for your response, however as you can see i'm new to python and your answer does not really help me that much, could you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending your user input to a list and you're comparing it with string.

If you're going to check a single password, don't append it to a list, set it to a string aswell. Or if you need to check a password inside a list you can do it like this.

```py
user_password = []
password = input("Enter what you would like your password to be. \n ENTER: ")
user_password.append(password)
print(f"Password created! Your password is: {user_password}")
enter_password = input("Enter password: ")
if enter_password in user_password: # This is the part that i've changed.
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print(f"{user_password} is wrong password")
```